# Prevent iframe navigation from changing top window history states

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I dont know if this is a bug that was introduced on latest version of chrome because it does not happen on any older version of chrome nor on any version of Firefox. Maybe it's a feature or a bug, but I still need a way to fix it but after trying from 2 hours, no luck.

The problem: I have a page with a button and an iframe inside. When I click the button I change the iframe SRC. It works fine. However, if after clicking the button I click the BACK button of chrome browser, it makes the iframe reload the SRC that was assigned.

When I click the BACK button of chrome, it should not mess with iframe history. This problem just started happening now, only on latest version of chrome.

Any way I can fix this using the `history` object, I mean, preventing iframe navigation to affect the top window history?

Comment: You can try running an iframe in the sandbox mode by adding a `sandbox` attribute.

Comment: I cant use sandbox, the iframe has to access lots of elements/share variables with the parent page.